# unable to create signed apk (keystore) android studio 1.4.1

Tags: android, android-studio, keystore, android-keystore

I saw many tutorials in which the user is able to select the folder to create new keystore in....but in android studio 1.4.1.... I can only select *.jks files. Also I created a keystore using keytool (java) and then created the signed apk choosing existing keystore....I was able to create app-release.apk....but google is giving this error on upload 
You uploaded an APK signed with a certificate that is not yet valid. You need to sign your APK with a certificate that is currently valid. Learn more about signing.
You need to use a different package name because "com.example" is restricted.

Comment: Try to change your package application from "com.example" to "com.your_name.what_you_want". Probably you can't call your package "com.example"

Comment: change your package com.example is restricted,  also change it it in AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first error:
You uploaded an APK signed with a certificate that is not yet valid. You need to sign your APK with a certificate that is currently valid.

Answer: I had to change my system date to two days back and then again generate the keystore. ....or you can simply wait till your certificate becomes valid.

For the second error:
You need to use a different package name because "com.example" is restricted.

Answer: In Android Studio go to the tree hierarchy and right click your package name folder under "app/java/your_package_name" and go to refractor and then rename. A pop up will appear....choose rename package and rename it to something else than default com.example.package_name. Also change it in AndroidManifest.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have certain names like **com.example** and **com.google** in your package name. Your package name has to be unique in play store. 
Apart from that Android follows the same conventions for naming packages as Java does.

Generally to make it unique, the package is named like **yourDomainNameInReverse.YourAppname**

For example, the package name for Mozilla firefox android app is **org.mozilla.firefox**

Answer (score 0):

if you are using android studio the change `applicationId` in `build.gradle` file.

your current app id id like `applicationId "com.example.zyz"` then change it to `applicationId "com.testmyname.zyz"`

***no need to change/manage packages & code***

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps

> Select Project -> Click Build -> Click Generate Signed APK

then follow the process shown there..